# Function to Parse AST Tree Into String of Rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, nlp, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm currently working on a code generation problem, I'm trying to create a dataset of different scripts and their plain-text AST trees, so that I can map text to code (not the code directly but the AST tree instead).

Dataset sample:

```
       script                              AST tree rules                               
'params_fu_nc_na_me = []'       "root Assign targets Name id params_fu_nc_na_me ^ ^ ^ ^ value List ^ ^ ^ ^"
```

Now, In order to create this dataset, I need to, given a script like this:

```
params_fu_nc_na_me = []
```

Get the rules from the ast tree, to get the rules from an ast tree, first I need to get the ast tree of the script:

```
import ast

st = ast.parse('params_fu_nc_na_me = []')
ast_tree = ast.dump(st)
print(ast_tree)

# "Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='params_fu_nc_na_me', ctx=Store())], value=List(elts=[], ctx=Load()))])"
```

And then, I need to pass this `ast_tree` variable to a function which output should be:

```
parsed_ast_tree = "root Assign targets Name id params_fu_nc_na_me ^ ^ ^ ^ value List ^ ^ ^ ^"
```

I have seen this representation on [this repository](https://github.com/zysszy/TreeGen/blob/master/ATIS/ground/1.txt), in the repository, there is no preprocessing step, it just gets directly the ast tree rules, but in my case I need to process this rules from the ast tree.

So this is my issue: Having `ast_tree` as input, I need to create a function that outputs `parsed_ast_tree`. Then I could generalize the function to match more complex inputs but If you could provide me some ideas of how to start with this, that would be awesome.

Comment: Are you just trying to convert the AST back to text? If so, you can use `ast.unparse()` if you're on python 3.9, or something from the module `astor`, `astor.to_source()`

Comment: @Tabulate thanks for your response. Not really, I'm trying to parse `ast_tree` variable into `parsed_ast_tree`, so that I can get a processed ast tree in a string. That's the function that I need to find, I haven't found anything already built-in so I need to build a function that process this.